# XSLT Framework for Java

Tags: java, xslt

I'm looking for the right XSLT framework for my Java apps. Just like with XML you can choose between DOM, SAX or Stax, and each of them have their own pros/cons (pull/push stream processing, XML tree modification, etc.), I assume the same holds true for XSLT frameworks.

My application needs something that is fast, but does not require in-memory modification of the resultant tree or random access. Just quick, relatively-painless conversion of one type of XML to another. Thanks in advance for nudging me in the right direction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend that you use what's built into the JDK.  There's no need for a framework of any kind.

Comment: I assume this is `javax.xml.transform.*` and company?